# How can i use the percent symbol to calculate number in php

Tags: php

this is the code

```
$result = ($Y*$Z*$V+($Y*$Z*$V*($B*2.75%))+(($Y*$Z*$V*($N*1.37%))));
```

i'm trying to have a calculation value in result variable this code is having error at the parentheses after the percent symbol i guess i can't use the percent symbol. is there anyway to have percent symbol without error?

Comment: A programming language is not plain English

Answer (score 0):

In `PHP` you can't use the symbol `%` as a percentage,  because `%` is the [modulo operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

If you wanna using percentage try 2.75% into `(2.75/100)` so change like these:

```
$result = ($Y*$Z*$V+($Y*$Z*$V*($B*(2.75/100))+(($Y*$Z*$V*($N*(1.37/100)))));
```

Comment: This is not limited to `PHP` though